# Python List of Functions without Executing

Tags: python, list, random

I'm working on a Python project, and part of it is where it chooses a function from random via list. Unfortunately, when it's declaring the list, its executing the function. Is there a way to have a list of functions without them executing?

Here's example code:

```
import random
def a():
  global var
  var = 1
def b():
  global var
  var = 2
list = [a(), b()]
print(var)
```

Outcome:

```
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the functions themselves, not the results of calling them.

```py
list = [a, b]
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much! Sorry if the question seemed redundant.